# Have a field that is a time, need to find those outside of HH:MM AM/HH:MM PM format

Tags: sql-server

I am looking a table that has from and to times for the hours that a particular business is open in a SQL Server table and the data is entered char, not a time format.  It needs to be in the 12 hour format of MM:HH AM or PM.  There many not entered with the correct time format.  How can I create a Case statement or something to catch those in wrong format.

I've not tried anything, I don't know where to begin.

No code to show

I would expect 8am or 23:59 for example to show up in the case statement column with whatever fail message is entered.

Comment: Use the `time` datatype and worry about the formatting in your presentation; that's what it (the presentation layer) is there for.

Comment: And if you want to find out what values aren't valid `time` values, use `TRY_CONVERT`, which will return `NULL` in the event the value in invalid.

Comment: Please at least give several real examples of allowed and disallowed values, and what kind of query output you would expect for each.

Comment: you can use CHARINDEX to check for AM or PM in the string, so as a starter CASE WHEN CHARINDEX ('PM', DateField)= 0 AND CHARINDEX ('AM', DateField) =0 THEN 'NO AM/PM Marker' ELSE DateField END  --naturally you can put that sort of login in a WHERE also.   So for 8am, which you want to disallow, you could write a custom BOOLEAN function or use Regular Expressions to check it

Comment: @Larnu That kind of works but 8AM format is passing, I'm guess that is a convertible format.  Any idea, how to look for stuff without the standard 12-hour format?

Comment: @cato I believe that will work for my use case.  I will check out specific examples.  I may need to add some more logic in there because some times are entered without the 12-hour format and have some invalid characters like ; in the time.  The time format will be the most difficult it seems to do.

Answer (score 1):

My comments from under the question stand on this, but to reiterate them: Don't use a `char` to store date and time values. Using the wrong data type can (and will) cause you problems. You should be using the appropriate datatype (in this case `time`) and have your presentation layer handle the formatting.

Firstly, however, to explicitly answer your question, you state you want the format `HH:MM AM/PM`, which means you could use a `LIKE` expression:

```
SELECT TimeColumn
FROM YourTable
WHERE TimeColumn NOT LIKE '[0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] [AP]M';
```

This does, still, however, have flaws as it'll allow a value like `'19:00 AM'`. Thus, you could be more specific and do this:

```
SELECT TimeColumn
FROM YourTable
WHERE TimeColumn NOT LIKE '0[0-9]:[0-5][0-9] [AP]M'
  AND TimeColumn NOT LIKE '1[0-2]:[0-5][0-9] [AP]M';
```

Personally, I would actually add the above as a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` to stop the insertion of bad data, but you'll need to fix the data first:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
    ADD CONSTRAINT ck_ValidTime
    CHECK (TimeColumn NOT LIKE '0[0-9]:[0-5][0-9] [AP]M' AND TimeColumn NOT LIKE '1[0-2]:[0-5][0-9] [AP]M');
```

But, like I said, you could really be fixing your data type. I would firstly add a new column to store the old data:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD TimeStringColumn char(8);
GO
UPDATE YourTable SET TimeStringColumn = TimeColumn;
```

Then correct the values of your column and then alter the datatype:

```
UPDATE YourTable SET TimeColumn = TRY_CONVERT(char(8),TRY_CONVERT(time,'12:17 AM'),114);

ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN TimeColumn time(0);
```

If you want one good reason why you need to change your data type, according to your data `'12:58 AM'` is **after** `'10:01 PM'`.

Comment: I have no control over the source data I am pull from.  The application allows users to enter free text in the time fields unfortunately which is the whole reason we have this issue and it's stored as CHAR.  I will look at your solution. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @laurnu  I tried this query and got back example like this-7:00 AM    select ID, HR1
from Table 
where HR1  NOT LIKE '0[0-9]:[0-5][0-9] [AP]M'
  AND HR1  NOT LIKE '1[0-2]:[0-5][0-9] [AP]M';

Comment: Any idea why these didn't get excluded?

Comment: Your post states the format was `hh:mm am/pm` @JavidCode2015. That example you gave is missing the leading `0`, that isn't the format `hh:mm` it's `h:mm`.

Comment: Ok sorry, I was wrong in the OP.  It can be anything with 1-9, I guess I can remove the 0 from the where clause.

Comment: Then yes, you would remove the leading `0` from the first `LIKE` expression. but fixing the data type is still the real solution.

Comment: That is kind of what I'm trying to do /;